# TypeScript: merging interfaces across files

Tags: interface, merge, typescript

I'm building a site in TypeScript and have been given a JS class to use that hooks into JQuery (ie you access it through

```
$.scPlayer.functionName()
```

The core JQuery definition in jquery.d.ts doesn't know about this, of course, so the compiler throws an error (even if the actual code works in the browser). So I'm trying to merge the JQueryStatic interface with one I've created, ie

```
interface JQueryStatic
{
    scPlayer:any;
}
```

From what I can tell, the TS compiler should recognise that these two interfaces are the same and merge them, adding my property to the other interface.

Now, this works fine if I include that in the JQuery definition file, either within the existing definition (obviously) or as a new, separate JQueryStatic interface... but ideally I'd like to avoid changing that for the sake of my forgetful future self, so I tried to create that new interface in a separate definitions file. But this doesn't work - it seems my new interface just overrides the JQuery one.

Is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interface works fine. I have added it next to `jquery.d.ts` in a file named `scplayer.d.ts` in Visual Studio.

I grabbed the jQuery type definition from nuget.

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    scPlayer: any;
}
```

This keeps the interface separate to the jQuery definition.

[image: Solution Explorer]

Comment: That's weird - still not working for me. Can I ask how you're importing/including the definition files? I'm using:
 
`/// <reference path="definitions/scplayer.d.ts"/>`
`/// <reference path="definitions/jquery.d.ts"/>`

Comment: Actually, I've just grabbed the latest definition files and it's working fine now, hey ho. Cheers :)

Comment: Does it need to be in the same folder?